# Can EOS be run with one node?

Tags: nodeos, dpos

When I was working with Proof of Authority and Ethereum I recall there was a minimal number of nodes (which I think was two).

For PoW one node was definitely possible.

For testing can setup just one node with EOS? I am unsure of the requirements under dPOS.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, one BP is enough.

```
$ nodeos --producer-name eosio --enable-stale-production
```

should be enough to start producing blocks on a chain with one node.